# Istio ingress is creating internal loadbalancer without annotations

Tags: amazon-eks, istio, istio-gateway

When I deploy istio-ingress helm chart, it is creating the Load balancer service which is creating an NLB  in private subnet in EKS.

I didnt set any annotations as shown below on service level. However it is still creating NLB in private subnet.

```
 # To generate an internal load balancer:
    # --set serviceAnnotations.cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type=internal
    #serviceAnnotations:
    #    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "internal"
```

What could be the reason behind this? I just deployed the istio-ingress helm chart without overriding any default values. And looks like by default it should created an NLB in public subnet

If I want hit the application exposed through internal loadbalancer from public, how to do it?

Comment: Looks like the annotations you're mentioning are for GCP, yet you're talking about EKS and AWS.

Set these annotations on the ingress gw service to create a public-face NLB:

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb`
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing`


(ref: https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints/tree/main/patterns/istio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting the below annotations

```
service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-attributes: "load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled=true"
```